# SQL code inside PHP code

Tags: php, sql

I want to make my code as clean as possible and this is how it looks like at the moment:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users"
        ."(Avatar, Biography, Birth_Date, Email, Location, Password, Profile_Views, Real_Name, Reputation, Signup_Date, Username) VALUES "
        ."('default',"
        ." 'User since ".date("d-m-Y")."',"
        ." '0000-00-00',"
        ." '".$email."',"
        ." 'default',"
        ." '".hash("sha256", $password)."',"
        ." 0,"
        ." 'default',"
        ." 0,"
        ." '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."',"
        ." '".$this->username."'"
        .");";
```

As you can see it's quite messy, so, what's a good way to put SQL code inside PHP?

Comment: Parameterized queries

Comment: Not only is it messy, but it's terribly insecure.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.

Comment: Also remember that you don't need to have all the string concatenations. You can have the string as multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and Parameterized Queries. You *do* like *not* being a victim of SQL Injection, right? Of course.

```
$query = <<<_E_
INSERT INTO Users
  (Avatar, Biography, Birth_Date, Email, Location, Password, Profile_Views, Real_Name, Reputation, Signup_Date, Username)
  VALUES ('default', :bio, '0000-00-00', :email, 'default', :pass, 0, 'default', 0, :singup, :uname);
_E_;
$params = array(
  'bio'    => 'User since'.date("d-m-Y"),
  'email'  => $email,
  'pass'   => hash("sha256", $password), 
  'singup' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'uname'  => $this->username,
);

// you also like checking return values, right?
// of course.
if( ! $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query) ) { die($dbh->errorInfo()); }
if( ! $stmt->execute($params) ) { die($stmt->errorInfo()); }
```

That more or less assumes PDO, but MySQLi is similar if I recall correctly.

Comment: Do I appreciate what you did? _Of course_. I learned much from this answer, thank you.

Comment: Do I like asking rhetorical questions and then answering them myself? *Of course.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` and it's less messy but that's a really bad solution, as it doesn't add any security.

You should use [prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

From linked page:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") ".
    $mysqli->connect_error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$id = 1;
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: `sprintf` shouldn't even be an option.

Comment: sprintf could be an option

Comment: He asked a way to make it less messy, it's not my job or problem if he doesn't want to make it better or more secure.  `sprintf` would at least be more readable for the next guy who comes along and has to fix it (implement prepared statements).

Comment: *"it's not my job or problem"*... why bother answering then?

Comment: I answer because I like to help. Why else? It was a simple answer, why overcomplicate it like everyone.  I'm not here to preach but to _help answer questions_.  If someone asks me "how do I get to the bank?" should i tell them "two blocks east" or should I tell them "you shouldn't go to the bank, you should go to the credit union."?  Think about it @WesleyMurch

Comment: The bank's over there across the highway. Seems like running across 6 lanes of traffic is the fastest most direct way (the alternative is walking 12 blocks which would take a while). Not my job/problem if you get hit by a bus.

Comment: My point is only that if you answer you do have to accept some amount responsibility. Some people are dumb enough to play in traffic. No offense meant, take care.

Comment: @mmmshuddup I appreciate your effort in helping me, but I have to say that the Sammitch answer helped me much. Thanks to him not only I have solved my problem, but I also have learned much. I think that the purpose of this platform is not just problem solving but learning too. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports multi line strings

so for example

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    column = value
  AND
    column2 = value2
";
```

is often how i write mine. As for the variable substitution, use Parameterized queries so instead of using static values for in where clause you would replace that with either one of the following:

PDO

```
WHERE
  column = ':col1'
```

or Mysqli

```
WHERE
  column = ?
```

All of the time sticking to the multi line string, indenting with 2 spaces

as an example with mysqli

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    column = ?
  AND
    column2 = ?
";
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting use of multiline strings.

Comment: Whats wrong with multi line strings ?

Comment: How ?  ... What makes adding a new line insecure ?

Comment: Well, if you write your SQL as a single string, anyone savvy enough can intercept it and read the string without issue (unless I misunderstand something and am talking rubbish). Whereas prepared statements use late-binding and make getting the values sent to the SQL server much harder.

Comment: That has NOTHING to do with mutli line strings, You still need to set up the prepared statement. The first part is an example, and the second is saying to use prepared statements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49427/discussion-between-nigel-nquande-and-user1281385)